# Have Twig asset() calls return a relative URL

Tags: symfony, assets

As part of an export process in a Symfony2 application, I need to have all Twig asset() calls return just a relative path, like so:

```
images/image.png
```

Default behavior is to prefix these with a '/' character. How do I get rid of that forward slash? I only want to change it for this one process, not for the rest of the application.

Comment: And why? Twigs asset() detects in what context the application run, and prepends it with the given relative path

Comment: Because I'm exporting this as a flat HTML file intended for use in an iPad app. Apparently, leaving the forward slash on there means these files try and reference whatever iPad's docroot is rather than the app's file location... at least, that's what the iPad app author tells me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not terribly fond of this solution, but it works:

```
{{ asset('something.png') | slice(1) }}
```

`slice(x, y)` creates a substring starting with x, with length y (if provided).

Comment: The problem is that I can't modify the Twig template files; this process is making a static copy of a part of the website's final displayed HTML pages, but the site itself must remained unmodified.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure I understand completely what you're trying to accomplish, but two things come to mind that might be helpful. First, you could write your own Assetic extension. 
There's a good blog entry showing this here: http://richardmiller.co.uk/2011/05/24/symfony2-make-your-own-assetic-filter/  I've never done it before, but it seems that you'll want to pay attention to AssetInterface::setTargetPath().

Second, you might have some luck with the assets_base_urls setting. See here for more info on that: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/configuration/framework.html#assets-base-urls

Comment: The assets_base_urls parameter can't be changed when the app is running, it seems like.

An Assetic extension would probably be the most robust way to do what I'm after, and I'll look further into that at a later time.

For now, I ended up taking the resulting HTML string after rendering the template and used a series of str_replace() calls to get rid of the forward slash for images, JS files, links, and CSS files.

I'm marking your answer as the correct one, since your comments lead  me in a great direction for this question.